PyQt5 How to ignoriere /dev/input/eventX events and only use one specific event device?
I have some issues with my PyQt5 GUI running on my Raspberry Pi. I sometimes need to plug in a USB Audio card into my raspberry pi while operating the GUI. When I touch the screen while plugging/unplugging this audio card, my GUI gets stuck and does not listen to any new touch inputs. The problem does not occur when i wait for a few seconds after plugging/unplugging the device, so the problem is obviously related to this usb device.
In the following picture, there is the TexasInstruments USB Audio codec with ID No.7. As long as this usb device is plugged in, the /dev/input shows an "event0". The "event1" is the one from my touchscreen which is actually being used by the GUI.

In the picture above you can see my xinputs and my events. The /event0 is created by my audio codec which causes the issues (id=7) and /event1 is my i2c-touchscreen (id=8). Suspiciously, the audio codec is detected as "slave keyboard" which I am not sure if this could also have an impact on my troubles.
I stumbled over some threads which indicated that this problem may be linked to multitouch which causes some issues on PyQt5. I also tried to use the "grab" method of EVIOCGRAB. The code seems to work but I still have the same issues. Maybe it is because EVIOCGRAB grabs the device after the very first event of the audio card and since the GUI detects the first event as well, it nevertheless crashes.
Here's the code:
dev0 = "/dev/input/event0"
try:
   fd0 = os.open(dev0, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NDELAY)
   if fd0 >= 0:
        fcntl.ioctl(fd1, 0x40044590, 1)  # EVIOCGRAB = 0x40044590
        print("Grabbed ", dev0)
except:
   pass

I am not very familiar with the whole input x-server management thing but I think I need to perform some configurations either via udev rules or somewhere else.
Can someone help me resolving this issue?
Thanks
